# which phone need to do auto-start code?

Tags: android, autostart

How to find in which phone need to do auto-start code? Means I know In MI device it is required for auto-start But don't know about others.

**Vodafone VFD 513 (OS 7.1.1)** mobile required auto-start?

Comment: Xiaomi, Oppo, One Plus, Vivo, Lenovo, Huawei, Vivo, Samsung (some models). Not sure about vodafone. (May be many more manufacturers)

Comment: Here is a [useful link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793)

Answer (score 0):

You can make tests using the android simulation when you compile your app.
I recommend you install many types with variable versions and test them.
I think that is a good way for make sure about it.
There are some extra plugins that you can install on your Android Studio too.
I recommend for you make a search about what plugins is useful for you case and how to install them.